# Teams SDK events - determine if Team has been deleted

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a fairly basic Teams app I've been developing, that has a bot associated with it. The bot is a simple NodeJS application, that us just waiting on events sent by my teams app to it

I see the teams `conversationUpdate` Type and some associated `eventType` in the SDK docs.

Is there an easy way to detect if the actual Team itself has been deleted?

i.e I have a Team, I add my app to it and create a tab in the team for the app. I can detect that the app has been added to the team, by checking the `teamMemberAdded` eventType.

But, I'm unsure if i can use the `teamMemberRemoved` eventType to determine if the Team has been deleted

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Bots do not receive an event when its containing team is deleted.

If you are storing team and channel details for proactive messages then you can clean it up when you get "NotFound" error code in exception while sending a message.